# How to manage game state data on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm not sure how to implement what I want to do.
I want a simple online turn-based game in Java. Clients are going to make request with their input and the server will respond if the movement is possible.

My question is that I need to store somehow the current state of a match between two players and I don't know what to use. Should I get the user's match data from the datastore, the modify it and finally put in datastore again? Will this going to be fast?

Is there another method o any idea?

I can't have a static ArrayList with that data, isn't it?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for karma, not 'bad' enough to warrant a -1 score imo

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [channel api](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html).  More specifically, look at the [tic-tac-toe example](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html#Example_Tic_Tac_Toe_Application).

Comment: I want to use Android so channel api isn't supported :(

Comment: Since all you're doing is making a request, you should be able to make it work with an android app.  As you can see, a lot of people would like that: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4189
That will end up being hacky though, and there doesn't seem to be wide examples.  That being said, have you considered making a mobile web app?  That would make it much easier for your game to run on iphones as well, and even ipads/tablets.  If this solution doesn't work for you, then you're going to have to keep track in datastore, or at least some sort of custom session object.

Comment: Using the MemCache service might be a bit faster than using Datastore, and you can even set the session objects to expire in MemCache.

Comment: @hatboyzero, but you can't rely on data staying in memcache. Per the app engine memcache docs (found here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html#When_to_Use_a_Memory_Cache ) "...when considering whether to store a value solely in the memcache and not backed by other persistent storage, be sure that your application behaves acceptably when the value is suddenly not available."  In other words, games can randomly be dropped.

Comment: @Dave Yup -- I probably should have said "faster than using just Datastore", but thanks for the correction :)

Comment: While adding memcache will surely increase overall performance of the entire application, the performance of a single game will probably not be increased noticeably since every turn is a write operation and would need to purge data relevant to the game from memcache in order to maintain cache correctness.

Comment: @Dave I agree with that. Every turn is a write. Why is going yo increase overall performance?
Edit answer so I can accept it